# How to increment app badge number for each push notification received

Tags: javascript, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase cloud functions to send a user push notifications. I dont understand JS well but I would like to be able to auto-increment the apps badge number through the notification payload and increase the number by 1 for each notification recieved. This is what I have now. I have read the documentation for firebase but I dont think I have enough JS understanding to figure out what they are describing.

```
exports.sendPushNotificationLikes = functions.database.ref('/friend-like-push-notifications/{userId}/{postId}/{likerId}').onWrite(event => {
const userUid = event.params.userId;
const postUid = event.params.postId;
const likerUid = event.params.likerId;
if (!event.data.val()) {
    return;
}

// const likerProfile = admin.database().ref(`/users/${likerUid}/profile/`).once('value');

const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/users/${userUid}/fcmToken`).once('value');

// Get the follower profile.
const getLikerProfilePromise = admin.auth().getUser(likerUid);

return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise, getLikerProfilePromise]).then(results => {
    const tokensSnapshot = results[0];
    const user = results[1];

    if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
        return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send to.');
    }

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'New Like!',
            body: '${user.username} liked your post!',
            sound: 'default',
            badge: += 1.toString()
       }
    };

    const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());

    // Send notifications to all tokens.
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {
            // For each message check if there was an error.
            const tokensToRemove = [];
        response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
            const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
            console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
            // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
            if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
                error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
                }
             }
        });
        return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
    });
});
```

});

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is what the issue is:

```
const payload = {
   notification: {
       title: 'New Like!',
       body: '${user.username} liked your post!',
       sound: 'default',
       badge: += 1.toString()
   }
};
```

Assume you have a notification count property available in your schema say `notificationCount` then you can do this:

```
const payload = {
   notification: {
       title: 'New Like!',
       body: `${user.username} liked your post!`,
       sound: 'default',
       badge: Number(notificationCount++) // => notificationCount + 1
   }
};
```

Also on this `body: '${user.username} liked your post!'`, this will be saved as `"user.username like your post!"`. This is not the behaviour you want, what you should be doing is this:

```
body: `${user.username} liked your post!`
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the line in question:

```
 badge: += 1.toString()
```

Careful of type conversion assumptions. Adding "1" + "1" will give you "11", not "2". Why not try something like:

```
badge: `${targetUser.notificationCount + 1}`
```

This is assuming the notificationCount is a key in your schema, and that it is typed as a string. You will need to persist the target user's notification count somewhere so it can be incremented when a new notification comes in.  It could also be an integer and then the string interpolation is unnecessary, i.e.:

```
badge: targetUser.notificationCount + 1
```

Also, be aware that your string interpolation here needs to be wrapped in backticks instead of single quotes, i.e.:

```
body: `${user.username} liked your post!`
```

I can't tell how the interactions are mapped in your database. This approach requires persisting and updating the notification count of the target user.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean: "Also, be aware that your string interpolation here needs to be wrapped in backticks instead of single quotes, i.e.:"
Are they not already wrapped correctly? But yes, this has given me "undefined" instead of the users username

Comment: In your example above for the ```body``` value you're using single quotes. The ```${}``` will be treated as just a regular string. You need to use the backtick (above the tab key) for the string interpolation to work. (` vs ') If you're using an IDE, the highlighting of the stuff inside the ```${}``` should change too. [MDN docs re template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)